# How to validate postcode in a form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a postcode using JavaScript.

I have my regex.

```
^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

This is my function so far, not sure how to implement regex.

```
function validatePostcode()
{
var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;

}
```

Any other suggestions that would format a postcode that matches;
CF24 9DG

Comment: what is your country

Comment: Can you please clarify what you have problem with? Clearly you've read something like [MDN Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions) to see how to use it and already have some sort of regular expression...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function validatePostalCode(){
    var regExp = /^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$/;
    var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;

    if( regExp.test( postcode ) ){
        // Do something here, result is true.
    } else {
        alert("result is false");
    }
}
```

You can try it out in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cedriking/5b8wtf1f/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**JavaScript test() Method**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) `RegExpObject.test(string)` that returns:

- `TRUE` if the input `string` matches the `RegExpObject` regex
- `FALSE` if the input `string` *does not* match the `RegExpObject` regex

Your validator function should look like this:

```
var validatePostCode = function(postCode) {
  var parsePostCode = 'your_regex';
  return parsePostCode.test(postCode);
};

var postCode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
validatePostCode(postCode); // calling the validator function
```